# How to generate a hash value in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, hash, midp

How can I generate hash value for a byte array, in J2ME?

It doesn't have to be very very secure but it should be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Josh Bloch in his Effective Java book:

```
public int hashCode() {
   int result = 17;
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result = 31*result + (int)array[i];
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: do you by any chance remember the reasoning why to use 31? It is a prime number, but there was some other reason too that I dont remember.

Comment: i think that bloch wrote that for some reasons backed up by mathematical theories prime number is used. it allows uniform distribution of keys in the hash table preventing creation of linked lists of values whose keys have the same hash code

Comment: I just can't get why result is instantiated with the 17 value. And the  31 integer seems to be 37 in the Google Books scanned version http://books.google.com/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Josh+Bloch+prime+hash&source=bl&ots=UZPXbskI2Z&sig=y5CKy0M0SBuxBtpFrym27B4AqpA&hl=en&ei=_12QSqjoIJSxlAfK-9m9DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score -2):

If you already have a dependency on [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) you may as well use [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html):

```
new HashCodeBuilder().append(bytes).toHashCode();
```

Comment: Apache Commons is for Java SE - not applicable to Java ME / MIDP